# Rubber insides and circuit transparent sheets of USB keyboard don't work outside of plastic case

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, keyboard

I have very little knowledge of electronics and circuits, so I apologize in advance if the question is dumb. I couldn't find answer anywhere.

I am trying to remove plastic part of my keyboard and have it be only that white rubber part on the inside with those transparent circuit sheets.  Reasons are I can't see which letter is where, so I wanted to challenge myself in a weird way and second was that it feels nicer.

I disassembled my keyboard and I saw those pins on microcontroller, and found a datasheet for it. I thought that the microcontroller (on one side green on other brownish board) sends current through that transparrent circuit sheet and checks if there is a pressed key. With that in mind I put the sheets with rubber keys over it on my wooden desk and placed microcontroller over the pins the exact same way as it was in the keyboard. Problem is, it does not work, numlock led diode is still lit on, but it won't change when I press the numlock key.

EDIT
My phone camera died few days ago, so I found few photos online that could better explain it:

[image]

I wanted to have these parts inside of keyboard without black plastic around them sitting on my desk.

Questions:

- Is it possible for current to go through those circuits if I change black plastic for wooden table?
- Do the little pins (on picture bottom left on keyboard) that connect to microcontroller have to be on certain surface or is wood fine for them too?

Desk:

[image]

Comment: Add a couple of photos so we can see your setup.

Comment: @Transistor i couldn't take photos, but hope this is enough

Comment: I think we understood that part. I wanted to see what "*and placed microcontroller over the pins*" looked like. There is usually a clamp to ensure even and firm pressure between the flexible circuit boards (the keyboard matrix) and the keyboard controller PCB edge connector. Just placing them on top of each other is unlikely to work.

Comment: @Thanks alot, that message combined with me cutting the part that makes firm pressure between microcontroller and pins did it. It works great :) Im new to stack exchange too, do you need to post answer now so i can aprove it?

Comment: Answer posted. I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually a clamp to ensure even and firm pressure between the flexible circuit boards (the keyboard matrix) and the keyboard controller PCB edge connector. Just placing them on top of each other is unlikely to work.

You can see some details on a project I did using a keyboard and some footswitches in [Soldering on keyboard controller circuit board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179275/soldering-on-keyboard-controller-circuit-board/243881#243881). I use it for advancing video slide presentations with my feet.